# Redshift - Extracting data from table based on filter condition

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have some sales data that shows if a store has done a sale or not. I am trying to pull out all stores that have no sale done till date. Given below is the query and the sample data I am working with.

```
store_name,sale_made,count
store_a,0,100
store_a,1,23
store_b,1,18
store_c,0,32
store_d,0,50
store_d,1,70
```

Expected output:

```
store_name,sale_made,count
store_c,0,32
```

Reason being only store_c in that list has `sale_made = 0` and no `sale_made = 1`

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this

```
SELECT store_name FROM table
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(sale_made)=0
```